# Java compiler api with springboot | Issue running under tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, java-compiler-api

I'm creating a file dynamically on execution of an api,

Code for it looks like:

```
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnosticsCollector, null, null);
fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File(Constants.PROCESSING_SCRIPTS_LOCATION)));
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", "--location of jar separated by :--"))
CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnosticsCollector,
    optionList, null, fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile)));
```

This works completely fine, when used with "mvn spring-boot:run".

But when we create war of the application and put that into tomcat container, it doesn't work there for all the internal code(our application) references it says: "package ... does not exist".

We tried setting things like putting our application war in lib(directory of tomcat) or adding more dependent jar/war on classpath before calling "compiler.getTask" but none of it worked. Please let us know what can be done here to make it work.

Comment: How are you building your WAR file? If it a multi module project? Running the war is completely different to mvn spring-boot:run. You would have to specifically have a WAR providing module that imports all your other dependencies created by your other maven modules.

Comment: the imports which are not working are specifically on usecase when we're using java compiler api, in other cases(files which are using other modules are working). Also all dependent modules are present as dependency in pom of build module